# Jordan forms of a real 3×3 matrix X satisfying $X^2+X+I=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

It seems $X^2+X+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $X$, but it does not have real root, so does this matrix has real Jordan form?

Comment: does there exist a $3 \times 3$ real matrix that satisfies this equation. the third root must be real, say $k.$ the characteristic poly is $(\lambda - k)(\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1)$ and the minimal polynomial must be the characteristic polynomial. does not the annihilating poly divides the char poly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a matrix does have a Jordan normal form with complex entries.  Because it's a real matrix, its complex Jordan blocks come in conjugate pairs.  In fact, this Jordan form must also be diagonal.

It also has a [real normal form](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).

Comment: One more question, how to prove X2+X+I=0 is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @Joseph the minimal polynomial must divide it.  What are the other possibilities, and why don't they apply?